# C# Database Context error exiting thread without throwing exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Having trouble figuring out why this code is causing the thread to exiting without error or throwing exception when for the connection string im using a server that doesnt exist (trying to handle that case). It also causes the main thread to exit too as this is in a windows service.

```
DbContext dbContext = new DbContext(ConnectionString());
var databases = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(queryStr);
foreach (var database in databases) //<- dies here
{
  //other code
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the Windows event log? Exceptions occurring in a parallel thread without callback handling can cause the thread (or the whole service in your case) to abort. Still there should be a log entry for the exception in the event log eventually pointing you to the error.

Comment: Thanks ChriPfless, Didnt see anything I could use in the event log, but i did cut down the timeout for the connection and finally started getting the exception to catch and handle